# Jquery offset return just one number while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web page and I need to get the current top position of my page elements.

I have some div that each of them have height of `100%` and I have my content there.

I want to get these div(s) position from top and work with that. but when I do it, it just return one number, and does not change while scrolling.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<header id="header">
   <div id="menu-div" class="container-full">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#">TEST</a>
            <a href="#">TEST</a>
            <a href="#">Test</a>
            <a href="#">Test</a>
            <a href="#">Test</a>
            <a id="request-demo-a" class="pull-right" href="#">TEST demo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
   </header>


   <div id="first-div" class="center a-div">
   test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>
   </div>


   <div id="full-div" class="container a-div">

        test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>
        </div>

  <div id="other-div" class=" a-div">
  <br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>

  </div>



  <div id="other-div" class=" a-div">
  <br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/><br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>test content here...<br/>

  </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.a-div{
    height:100%;
}


#full-div{
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: white;
    z-index:5;

}


#first-div{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    color:white;
    z-index:-1;


}
#menu-div{
    background: white;
    padding:7px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:10;
}


#menu-div .container a{
    margin-left: 15px;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:large;
}

#request-demo-a{
    padding:5px;
    border: 2px solid #FF8000;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
    background: orange;
    text-decoration: navajowhite;
}

#request-demo-a:hover, #request-demo-a:focus{
    background: #FF8000;
}
```

**JavaScript (Jquery):**

```
$(function(){
        /**start:Scroll*/
        $(document).scroll(function(){
         $("#request-demo-a").html($('#full-div').offset().top);
         /// I want this return current value of full-div!
         //And when it become equel 0 do something! (This is just example)

        });
        /**End: Scroll*/      
})
```

[JSFiddle-Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ykxzva7m/7/)

I want to get the position of `#full-div`  and use it, when it become equal to 0, do something (means when arrived to top) and for others div(s) I want to do something in certain position.

**But why does `$('#full-div').offset().top` just return one number while scrolling?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The offset doesn't change on scroll, `offset()` retrieves the current position of an element relative to the document, and the entire document is scrolling, so nothing really changes, the element is still at the exact same position inside the document.

If you want the distance scrolled, use `scrollTop`, and then compare that to the elements offset to see if the page was scrolled the same amount as the elements distance to the top of the document

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(){

    var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    var offset   = $('#full-div').offset().top;

    if ( offset <= scrolled ) {
       // element is scrolled to top or above
    }

});
```

Comment: So, you mean I should use `on`?

Comment: @Askion - no, I just used `on`, as it's the preferred way to attach an event handler, it has nothing to do with the answer

Comment: Thanks.Another question, How can I tell, when full-div arrived to (something like) header, do something!?

Comment: Depends on what "header" is ?

Comment: Well, all the elements are inside the same document, I can't really understand how you'd scroll `#full-div` to `header`, they never move ?

Comment: Yes, but #header has a position, that #full-div can be in that position while scrolling, Am I right ?

Comment: Not really, but I think you're asking how to know when `#full-div` is in the same place as `header` was on first page load, and that's a truly strange requirement that you generally shouldn't need ?

Comment: I need it, because I want to change my menu, when that #full-div arrived there. Can you help please or any idea?

Comment: Use the code I posted, and just subtract the 53 pixels of height that your header spans, that get's the bottom of the fixed header instead of the top of the window